# como importar un projecto a otra aplicación android

Tags: android

tengo una aplicación en android la cual necesito que utilice módulos de una aplicación que ya había creado anteriormente, el problema que tengo actualmente es que no se como convertirla en una dependencia de mi aplicación actual para poder utilizar los módulos de esta aplicacion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para agregar modulos (submodulos) a tu proyecto, se deben encontrar en la raíz de tu proyecto al mismo nivel de `/app`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Procedes a registrarlos dentro de `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':MYMODULE'
include ':SORICEL'
include ':PISICA'
```

y dentro del archivo `app/build.gradle` del proyecto

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    compile project(':MYMODULE')
    compile project(':SORICEL')
    compile project(':PISICA')
    ...
}
```

De esta forma al revisar la estructura del proyecto podrás ver el módulo principal y los submodulos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes copiar el modulo en la carpeta de tu proyecto, luego agrega la dependencia del proyecto en build.gradle

```
dependencies {
...
compile project(':tu-proyecto')
}
```

Comment: la debo importar? o solo agregarla como un modulo y en el que caso de que sea un modulo, de que tipo?

Comment: Debes copiar la aplicacion completa al directorio donde se encuentra tu carpeta "app" yo lo hago de forma manual, desde el explorador con Android Studio cerrado.

Comment: Dentro de la carpeta "/app" no es correcto ya que es el módulo principal. debe ser al mismo nivel.

Comment: @Jorgesys Aclaración: dije en la carpeta del /proyecto, no dentro de la carpeta de /app.